# How to create UniDac MySQL components in console application?

Tags: mysql, delphi, components, console-application, unidac

As preliminary information: I've never used a component which i can drag & drop to the formular designer in a console application.

At the moment i use:

- UniConnection
- UniQuery
- UniDataSource
- MySQLUniProvider

My question is now: How can i create these 4 components in a console application and how to use them correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: UniConnInst := TUniConnection.Create(NIL); UniConnInst.Provider := TMySQLUniProvider.GetProviderName; don't forget about database related settings and specific options(if used)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add a datamodule to your conosole applicaiton and drop the components there. Also you can create them by code. Just check the their properties and see how they are linked to each other.